# Is there a limit or max to the number of security rules in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need an application to support many users (>100,000).  Each of those users will have access to a number of folders or paths.  Each folder will need to be accessed by a number of users.  (It is a many-to-many relationship.)

If I need to have 500,000+ security rules, will I run into a limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Amended the title, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section under [Firestore rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) which you can take a look, the recommendations you basically need to look at are:

> Maximum number of expressions in a ruleset 10,000
>
> Maximum size of a ruleset  64 KB

Comment: I changed it to firestore seeing the link pointed there and the question is about firestore.

Comment: Maximum number of expressions in a ruleset 1,000 not 10,000, there was a typo in doc!